# Twitter API needs to be upgraded

Tags: javascript, url, twitter, oauth, openid

I am using `open id` js for user registration through social media in my website designed in jquery mobile and zend framework.All of them are working correctly besides twitter.Since the `twitter API has been upgraded from v1 to v1.1`.I created the new application.I have updated the `appid and twitter secret values.`
Still I am getting the following error.

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=the_screen_name&callback=jQuery19105400562318973243_1371733485507&_=1371733485508 400 (Bad Request)
```

where are the loose ends I am not able to point out? Explored alot.But didn't find the exact guidelines.Is there anyone faced the similar problem.
Will give regarding explanations.

**Update:**

The url used in twitter api v1.1 has changed.MAy be I need to go for the correct url.Any guesses...